# Using Aggregate function in where clause and a different column criteria

Tags: sql, function, average

```
select PO_Order_Qty, Avg([PO_Order_Qty])as totalAverage 
FROM [FirstStrike_Retail].[custom].[Whse_Pricing_QR]    
where item_code ='111' and PO_order_qty <(Avg([PO_Order_Qty])*2)
group by PO_Order_Qty
```

I am using the above sql in MS Sql to get the average on a particular item codes order qty. I am expecting only one return value.

And i need to eliminate if any of the qty is above twice the average.

Thanks
Xplr

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I am getting an error when i run this sql. I just need to find the average of a column on 2 criteria's(a) I want to pick the rows for the specific item code and (b) the po order qty should be less that twice the average

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use HAVING clause when checking the Aggregrate functions (MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG etc). I don't want to just give you the answer, but try something like this.

```
select PO_Order_Qty, Avg([PO_Order_Qty])as totalAverage 
FROM [FirstStrike_Retail].[custom].[Whse_Pricing_QR]    
where item_code ='111' 
group by PO_Order_Qty
HAVING PO_order_qty <(Avg([PO_Order_Qty])*2)
```

EDIT: try this based on your comment ... something like this

```
    select * 
    FROM [FirstStrike_Retail].[custom].[Whse_Pricing_QR]    
    where item_code ='111' 
      and PO_Order_Qty < 
          (select Avg([PO_Order_Qty])as totalAverage 
          FROM [FirstStrike_Retail].[custom].[Whse_Pricing_QR]) * 2
```

Comment: This will give me more than one. I just want one avg return value for the whole list.

Comment: I got the just the one return value by replacing the * with Avg([PO_Order_Qty])as totalAverage. And got the answer.Thanks